# Getting list of SVN users using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I've seen a lot of commands that use awk, grep, etc to do this and I just can't seem to make an alternative that doesn't use 3rd party applications or other languages.

I came up with

```
for /f %%a in ('svn log -q ^| findstr /r "\|(.*?)\|"') do echo %%a
```

but it doesn't return anything

This is what svn log -q returns:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
number | nameOfPerson | date +0000 (long date)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and I would like to get the nameOfPerson part.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by "using MS-DOS"? the OS from the 1980s? or are you talking about the Windows command prompt `cmd.exe`? Anyway, read he help of [`findstr /?`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) and you'll find out that it only supports very few search expressions...

Comment: I'd note two points: 1) Windows has [WSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) which can be scripted while leveraging various system's COM-components—including the [`RegExp` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40425324/720999). (Yes, MS tries hard to hide the fact WSH exists from the users—in an attempt to push them towards PowerShell and .NET, but still). 2) WIndows 7 and above (I think even Vista, but who cares?) have .NET and PowerShell preinstalled; so I really see no point in not using them.

Comment: I've spent all day reading about findstr and trying to get this to work. If findstr doesn't support what I've tried then what do you suggest?

Comment: Kyle, don't remove the `cmd` tag—it's essential to your question (even though you might be not aware of this, yet) ;-)

Comment: Oh, one more point—just in case: `svn log` supports the `--xml` command-line option, and the tool's output in that format can be parsed using [MSXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSXML)'s COM objects used in a WSH script.

Comment: And one more point, too, to maybe get you going faster: it's trivially possible to have a WSH script work in a command-line pipeline; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36449210/720999)'s how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the command line:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %A in ('svn log -q 2^>Nul') do @for %B in (%A) do @Echo:[%B]
```

In a batch double the percent signs:

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%A in (
  'svn log -q 2^>Nul'
) do for %%B in (%%A) do Echo:[%%B]
```

The second for is to trim the name from spaces.
You could as well set it to a variable `set "var=%%B"`